# Delete received Object from Parse Backend service with Swift, xcode

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to delete a received Photo with a button on tableview from parse with swift in x code, my problem is "I Got an error that says (object not found for delete)", and the following code is all i can write to delete this file, is there another way do delete the file or did I use the wrong code

```
 let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Photos")
    query.whereKey("recipientUsername", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
    query.whereKey("senderUsername", containsString: usernames[indexPath!.row])

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {
                object.deleteInBackground()
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Not sure why you're seeing that that error.  It would be better to do this in a single call, though: `PFObject.deleteAllInBackground(objects)`

Comment: Dear @danh still got the same error.